# unable to get data into plain text (table) from json data using angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json

I want to show json data into a table, but its showing the result as below shown. How to show json data in table in angular js.

```
userid  {{x.userid}}
status  {{x.status}}
```

Desired output:

```
userid 0000acfffe731122
status 3
```

Json data:

```
{  
   "userid":"0000acfffe731122",
   "status":3
}
```

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            device id
        </td>
        <td>
            {{names.userid}}
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            device status
        </td>
        <td>{{names.status}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script>
 var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
$http.get('https://example.com/abc', {
headers: { 'Authorization': 'Basic a2VybmVsc==' }
})
.then(function(response) {
    $scope.names = response.data;
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: your json data is an array or object?

Comment: its a JSON object

Comment: then why are you using `ng-repeat`?

Comment: yes ng- repeat is not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `names` object must be an *array* if you have to use `ng-repeat`, as that is what it is there for:

```
[{
  "userid": "0000acfffe731122",
  "status": 3
}];
```

See Demo below:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.names = [{
    "userid": "0000acfffe731122",
    "status": 3
  }];

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<table ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
    <td>user id -</td>
    <td>{{x.userid}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
    <td>status -</td>
    <td>{{x.status}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If it *can't* be an array you can use `names.userid` and `names.status` - see demo below:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.names = {
    "userid": "0000acfffe731122",
    "status": 3
  };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<table ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <tr>
    <td>user id -</td>
    <td>{{names.userid}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>status -</td>
    <td>{{names.status}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: what about  $scope.names = response.data;or data.records;

Comment: of course, you can do that by fetching the data from your server... I don't have access to it to show you a demo :)

Comment: still im getting like that only.

Comment: do a `console.log(response.data.record)` inside the `.then(function(){` to see how the data is coming from the url...

Comment: and also check if you have put `ng-app` and `ng-controller` on the html?

Comment: i have not given ng-app and ng-controller on the html .<html>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131974/discussion-between-kukkuz-and-swapna).